# Question on a submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^2$ and tangent vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X\subset \mathbb{C}^2$ (with complex coordinates $z,w$) be defined by the equation $|z|^2=|w|^2$.

If we see $\mathbb{C}^2$ as $\mathbb{R}^4$ with real coordinates $z=x+iy$, $w=u+iv$ then $X$ is a real submanifold of dimension 3 defined by $x^2+y^2-u^2-v^2=0$.

Question 1: is $X$ also a complex submanifold?

Question 2: is $(i,0)$ a tangent vector to $X$ in $(1,1)\in X$?

I think the answer is no to both questions. In particular for the second one it should be true that $T_{(1,1)}X\simeq Ker(df_{(1,1)})$ with $f= x^2+y^2-u^2-v^2=0$ and $df_{(1,1)}=(2,2,-2,-2)$. But $(i,0)=(0,1,0,0)$ in real coordinates and $df_{(1,1)}(0,1,0,0)\neq 0$.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Note, furthermore, that any complex manifold must have even real dimension.

Comment: I think, contrary to you and  @Ted, that the vector $(i,0)$ **is** tangent to $X$ at the point $(1,1)\in X$ : this is because I think that your equality $df_{(1,1)}=(2,2,-2,-2)$ is false and that it should be $df_{(1,1)}=(2,0,-2,0)$. What do **you** think is $df_{(z,w)}$ and what do you get with your formula when $z=1, w=1$ ? See my answer for my point of view.

Comment: Of course, @Georges is right. I fell in the trap of skimming the second part and not being careful. My apologies.

Comment: Thanks  for your gentlemanly  comment,  @Ted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Question 1**
Since $X\subset \mathbb R^4$ is a real hypersuface it has real dimension $3$ and so cannot be a complex manifold nor even a complex space since complex spaces have even real dimension.
(Beware that, if  $O\in \mathbb C^2$ denotes  the origin,  $X\setminus \{O\}$ is indeed a real manifold , but $X$ itself is not a real manifold because  it has a singularity at $O$)

**Question 2**
We have for $P=(a,b)=(p+iq,r+is)\neq O\in X\subset \mathbb C^2$ the relation $T_PX=\ker d_Pf$, where $$d_Pf:\mathbb C^2\to \mathbb R:(z=x+iy,w=u+iv)\mapsto 2(px+qy-ru-sv)$$ or in vector notation $$ d_Pf=(2p,2q,-2r,-2s)$$ If now $a=1,b=1$, we get $$d_Pf(z,w)=2(x-u) \quad [\operatorname {or in vector notation } d_Pf=(2,0-2,0)]$$ so that $T_Pf$ is the real hyperplane $$T_Pf=\{(z,w)\in \mathbb C^2\vert x=u\}$$ So, yes,  $(i,0)=(0+i,0+0i)\in T_Pf$ since for that vector $(i,0)$ one has $x=u=0$

**Supplementary remark**
 One may notice that the only complex line $L$ included in the $3$-dimensional real vector space $T_{(1,1)}X\subset \mathbb C^2$ is $$L=\{(0,w)\in \mathbb C^2\vert w\in \mathbb C\}$$